# How to reference separate file in azure pipelines template?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

How to pass in a separate file inside of a pipelines template?

Inside of a template I'm attempting to pass in a config file to markdownlint but when calling the template, I don't think the calling pipeline has access to this config file giving me the error

```
Cannot read or parse config file 'configs/.markdownlint.yml': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'configs/.markdownlint.yml'
```

Folder structure as follows: build (this is where template yaml lives) > configs > .markdownlint.yml

So is there a native (no script & git commands) way to pass in the separate file to the template?

Comment: How are you trying to access this file? Does it work when you fully qualify the path to the file with `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`?

Comment: I was able to figure it out - see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement this by checking out two repos (still getting used to azdo after using github actions for many years).

Example (following is in the template yaml in the template repo):

```
  - checkout: self
    path: service
  - checkout: templates
    path: templates

...
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'markdownlint ''$(Agent.BuildDirectory)''/service/some/dir/**/*.md --config ''$(Agent.BuildDirectory)''/templates/build/configs/.markdownlint.yml'
    displayName: Lint markdown
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. A note: You might find it more convenient, syntactically speaking, to know that system variables can be accessed as environment variables in scripts, so `$AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY` in Bash.